# Flask, Blueprint, current_app

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to add a function in the Jinja environment from a blueprint (a function that I will use into a template).

**Main.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(heysyni)
```

**MyBluePrint.py**

```
heysyni = Blueprint('heysyni', __name__)
@heysyni.route('/heysyni'):
    return render_template('heysyni.html', heysini=res_heysini)
```

Now in **MyBluePrint.py**, I would like to add something like :

```
def role_function():
    return 'admin'

app.jinja_env.globals.update(role_function=role_function)
```

I will then be able to use this function in my template. I cannot figure out how I can access the application since

```
app = current_app._get_current_object()
```

returns the error:

```
working outside of request context
```

How can I implement such a pattern ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message error was actually pretty clear :

> *working outside of request context*

In my blueprint, I was trying to get my application outside the 'request' function :

```
heysyni = Blueprint('heysyni', __name__)

app = current_app._get_current_object()
print(app)

@heysyni.route('/heysyni/')
def aheysyni():
    return 'hello'
```

I simply had to move the current_app statement into the function. Finally it works that way :

**Main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from Ablueprint import heysyni

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(heysyni)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Ablueprint.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

heysyni = Blueprint('heysyni', __name__)

@heysyni.route('/heysyni/')
def aheysyni():
    # Got my app here
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    return 'hello'
```

Comment: But the current_app can be used directly in function, why do i need to use _get_current_object() ?